# Normalisation and simplification of a plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'd like to make a graph that captures the impact of the intervention. As you can see in the plot below, the y-axis of my figure has different scales (e.g. values), making comparison difficult. Is it possible to normalise the y axis (0 and 1) on both figures? Is it also possible to create a plot that shows the intervention rate per day? For Monday, for example, display a black line without SEDM and a red line with

Sample code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Day, Time = ceiling_date(as.POSIXct(Time), '10 minutes')) %>% 
  summarise(kW= mean(kW)) %>%
  ungroup


df$Day<- factor(df$Day,levels = c( "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday", "Sunday"))
#as.POSIXct(df$Time,format="%H:%M")


ggplot(transform(df, Time = as.POSIXct(Time)),
       aes(x = Time,y =kW, group=Day)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(color=Day))  +
  #geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="", y="kW", title="Monthly electricity consumption without SEDM (House 3)") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = '%H:%M', date_breaks = '2 hours',expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)))+
  #facet_wrap(~Day, ncol=1 )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

Plot:

[image]

Data:

```
#for the first plot (without SEDM) first 300

    structure(list(structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), structure(c(41220, 
41280, 41340, 41400, 41460, 41520, 41580, 41640, 41700, 41760, 
41820, 41880, 41940, 42000, 42060, 42120, 42180, 42240, 42300, 
42360, 42420, 42480, 42540, 42600, 42660, 42720, 42780, 42840, 
42900, 42960, 43020, 43080, 43140, 43200, 43260, 43320, 43380, 
43440, 43500, 43560, 43620, 43680, 43740, 43800, 43860, 43920, 
43980, 44040, 44100, 44160, 44220, 44280, 44340, 44400, 44460, 
44520, 44580, 44640, 44700, 44760, 44820, 44880, 44940, 45000, 
45060, 45120, 45180, 45240, 45300, 45360, 45420, 45480, 45540, 
45600, 45660, 45720, 45780, 45840, 45900, 45960, 46020, 46080, 
46140, 46200, 46260, 46320, 46380, 46440, 46500, 46560, 46620, 
46680, 46740, 46800, 46860, 46920, 46980, 47040, 47100, 47160, 
47220, 47280, 47340, 47400, 47460, 47520, 47580, 47640, 47700, 
47760, 47820, 47880, 47940, 48000, 48060, 48120, 48180, 48240, 
48300, 48360, 48420, 48480, 48540, 48600, 48660, 48720, 48780, 
48840, 48900, 48960, 49020, 49080, 49140, 49200, 49260, 49320, 
49380, 49440, 49500, 49560, 49620, 49680, 49740, 49800, 49860, 
49920, 49980, 50040, 50100, 50160, 50220, 50280, 50340, 50400, 
50460, 50520, 50580, 50640, 50700, 50760, 50820, 50880, 50940, 
51000, 51060, 51120, 51180, 51240, 51300, 51360, 51420, 51480, 
51540, 51600, 51660, 51720, 51780, 51840, 51900, 51960, 52020, 
52080, 52140, 52200, 52260, 52320, 52380, 52440, 52500, 52560, 
52620, 52680, 52740, 52800, 52860, 52920, 52980, 53040, 53100, 
53160, 53220, 53280, 53340, 53400, 53460, 53520, 53580, 53640, 
53700, 53760, 53820, 53880, 53940, 54000, 54060, 54120, 54180, 
54240, 54300, 54360, 54420, 54480, 54540, 54600, 54660, 54720, 
54780, 54840, 54900, 54960, 55020, 55080, 55140, 55200, 55260, 
55320, 55380, 55440, 55500, 55560, 55620, 55680, 55740, 55800, 
55860, 55920, 55980, 56040, 56100, 56160, 56220, 56280, 56340, 
56400, 56460, 56520, 56580, 56640, 56700, 56760, 56820, 56880, 
56940, 57000, 57060, 57120, 57180, 57240, 57300, 57360, 57420, 
57480, 57540, 57600, 57660, 57720, 57780, 57840, 57900, 57960, 
58020, 58080, 58140, 58200, 58260, 58320, 58380, 58440, 58500, 
58560, 58620, 58680, 58740, 58800, 58860, 58920, 58980, 59040, 
59100, 59160), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2.951667, 41.055, 10.733333, 2.951667, 3.22, 4.83, 
    3.22, 3.22, 3.22, 2.951667, 3.488333, 13.416667, 3.22, 3.22, 
    13.416667, 43.738333, 3.22, 3.22, 3.22, 3.488333, 3.22, 3.22, 
    3.488333, 2.951667, 11.806667, 3.756667, 45.348333, 4.025, 
    4.025, 4.293333, 4.83, 4.83, 15.026667, 4.561667, 46.153333, 
    4.025, 4.025, 3.756667, 4.025, 4.293333, 44.275, 44.811667, 
    3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 
    3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 44.006667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 
    3.756667, 3.488333, 3.756667, 3.756667, 44.006667, 44.006667, 
    3.756667, 3.756667, 4.293333, 3.756667, 4.293333, 4.561667, 
    4.83, 4.025, 4.025, 24.418333, 4.561667, 4.025, 4.293333, 
    32.736667, 9.928333, 1.073333, 1.341667, 1.073333, 0.805, 
    20.93, 41.591667, 0.805, 0.805, 1.073333, 1.341667, 1.61, 
    2.415, 43.201667), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Day", 
"Time", "kW", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), row.names = c(NA, 300L
), class = "data.frame")

#for the second plot (with SEDM) first 500

   structure(list(Day = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(43380, 43440, 43500, 43560, 43620, 43680, 
    43740, 43800, 43860, 43920, 65700, 65760, 65820, 65880, 65940, 
    66000, 66060, 66120, 66180, 66240, 66300, 66360, 66420, 66480, 
    66540, 66600, 66660, 66720, 66780, 66840, 66900, 66960, 67020, 
    67080, 67140, 67200, 67260, 67320, 67380, 67440, 67500, 67560, 
    67620, 67680, 67740, 67800, 67860, 67920, 67980, 68040, 68100, 
    68160, 68220, 68280, 68340, 68400, 68460, 68520, 68580, 68640, 
    68700, 68760, 68820, 68880, 68940, 69000, 69060, 69120, 69180, 
    69240, 69300, 69360, 69420, 69480, 69540, 69600, 69660, 69720, 
    69780, 69840, 69900, 69960, 70020, 70080, 70140, 70200, 70260, 
    70320, 70380, 70440, 70500, 70560, 70620, 70680, 70740, 70800, 
    70860, 70920, 70980, 71040, 71100, 71160, 71220, 71280, 71340, 
    71400, 71460, 71520, 71580, 71640, 71700, 71760, 71820, 71880, 
    71940, 72000, 72060, 72120, 72180, 72240, 72300, 72360, 72420, 
    72480, 72540, 72600, 72660, 72720, 72780, 72840, 72900, 72960, 
    73020, 73080, 73140, 73200, 73260, 73320, 73380, 73440, 73500, 
    73560, 73620, 73680, 73740, 73800, 73860, 73920, 73980, 74040, 
    74100, 74160, 74220, 74280, 74340, 74400, 74460, 74520, 74580, 
    74640, 74700, 74760, 74820, 74880, 74940, 75000, 75060, 75120, 
    75180, 75240, 75300, 75360, 75420, 75480, 75540, 75600, 75660, 
    75720, 75780, 75840, 75900, 75960, 76020, 76080, 76140, 76200, 
    76260, 76320, 76380, 76440, 76500, 76560, 76620, 76680, 76740, 
    76800, 76860, 76920, 76980, 77040, 77100, 77160, 77220, 77280, 
    77340, 77400, 77460, 77520, 77580, 77640, 77700, 77760, 77820, 
    77880, 77940, 78000, 78060, 78120, 78180, 78240, 78300, 78360, 
    78420, 78480, 78540, 78600, 78660, 78720, 78780, 78840, 78900, 
    78960, 79020, 79080, 79140, 79200, 79260, 79320, 79380, 79440, 
    79500, 79560, 79620, 79680, 79740, 79800, 79860, 79920, 79980, 
    80040, 80100, 80160, 80220, 80280, 80340, 80400, 80460, 80520, 
    80580, 80640, 80700, 80760, 80820, 80880, 80940, 81000, 81060, 
    81120, 81180, 81240, 81300, 81360, 81420, 81480, 81540, 81600, 
    81660, 81720, 81780, 81840, 81900, 81960, 82020, 82080, 82140, 
    82200, 82260, 82320, 82380, 82440, 82500, 82560, 82620, 82680, 
    82740, 82800, 82860, 82920, 82980, 83040), class = c("hms", 
    "difftime"), units = "secs"), kW = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 6.976667, 6.976667, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 
    7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 
    7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 7.245, 13.416667, 30.053333, 
    4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 42.396667, 41.591667, 4.025, 
    4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.293333, 4.025, 4.025, 
    4.293333, 4.025, 4.025, 23.881667, 23.881667, 4.293333, 4.025, 
    4.293333, 42.665, 43.201667, 29.785, 4.293333, 16.636667, 
    4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.293333, 5.903333, 
    5.635, 5.903333, 31.126667, 5.635, 5.635, 5.635, 5.635, 5.635, 
    5.903333, 5.635, 5.635, 5.635, 39.176667, 60.106667, 75.67, 
    75.67, 76.475, 30.321667, 6.976667, 7.781667, 7.781667, 39.713333, 
    39.713333, 39.713333, 31.663333, 31.663333, 31.663333, 18.515, 
    31.663333, 37.298333, 49.91, 59.301667, 24.15, 28.711667, 
    30.59, 35.956667, 38.64, 41.055, 24.955, 42.665, 52.325, 
    43.47, 31.395, 50.983333, 52.325, 40.518333, 44.543333, 50.178333, 
    41.591667, 50.715, 54.74, 50.983333, 65.741667, 48.031667, 
    41.591667, 50.715, 28.98, 5.366667, 7.781667, 28.98, 16.368333, 
    4.561667, 4.561667, 2.683333, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.683333, 2.683333, 2.415, 2.415, 3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 
    4.293333, 5.366667, 5.635, 5.366667, 5.366667, 4.83, 4.83, 
    4.561667, 3.22, 2.951667, 2.951667, 3.22, 3.22, 3.22, 3.22, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.146667, 
    2.415, 2.146667, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.146667, 2.415, 2.415, 
    2.415, 2.415, 2.951667, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 
    2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 
    2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.683333, 2.683333, 2.683333, 
    2.683333, 2.683333, 2.415, 2.683333, 3.488333, 2.951667, 
    3.756667, 3.756667, 3.488333, 3.488333, 4.025, 4.025, 2.415, 
    2.415, 1.878333, 1.878333, 2.146667, 2.415, 1.878333, 2.146667, 
    2.146667, 2.146667, 1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 
    1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 
    1.878333, 1.878333, 1.878333, 3.488333, 3.22, 2.951667, 2.683333, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.683333, 
    2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.683333)), row.names = c(NA, 
300L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `scale` your "kW" variable with min and max like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df$Day<- factor(df$Day,levels = c( "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday", "Sunday"))
#as.POSIXct(df$Time,format="%H:%M")

maxs <- max(df$kW)
mins <- min(df$kW)
df$kW <- scale(df$kW, center = mins, scale = maxs-mins)

ggplot(transform(df, Time = as.POSIXct(Time)),
       aes(x = Time,y =kW, group=Day)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(color=Day))  +
  #geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="", y="kW", title="Monthly electricity consumption without SEDM (House 3)") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = '%H:%M', date_breaks = '2 hours',expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)))+
  #facet_wrap(~Day, ncol=1 )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

Output:

[image]